# Electrons can't orbit at any old radius

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, discrete, orbitals

Electrons can't orbit at any old radius from the atom's nucleus, but are rather restricted to only specific orbits at a fixed set of distances.  This is called orbital quantization.  Why this restriction?

Comment: The "why" questions are hard to answer. Why matter behaves according to quantum mechanical theory is not understood and very unlikely to be answered scientifically in the "near" future.

Comment: This restriction exists in the form proposed only in the Bohr model. In better models the nature of the orbital is such that “at a distance” is ill defined. Do you want the Bohr-de Broglie explanation?

Answer (score 4):

It is not true to say that electrons orbit at fixed distances from the atomic nucleus. Our best models suggest that the positions associated with an electron in an atom can be defined only in terms of a probability function, known for historical reasons as an atomic orbital. There are countless illustrations of typical atomic orbitals on the internet.

In the early days of quantum theory it was believed that electrons did orbit the nucleus much as planets orbit a star, and that the orbits could be only at fixed distances. The underlying idea was that electrons had associated waves with well-defined wavelengths. The allowable orbits were those which corresponded to integer multiples of the associated wavelength, so it was possible for a standing wave to form.